# PHPPresentation Adding Text After Using setColSpan() Doesn't Work

Tags: php, phppresentation

I'm try to add text following a colspan column and nothing I've tried has worked. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
// Create a shape (table)
$tableShape = $currentSlide->createTableShape(3);
$tableShape->setHeight(1200);
$tableShape->setWidth(960);
$tableShape->setOffsetX(0);
$tableShape->setOffsetY(0);

// Add row
$row = $tableShape->createRow();
$cell = $row->nextCell();
$cell->setColSpan(2);
$cell->createTextRun('Row 1 Colspan column 1');

$Cell = $row->nextCell();
$Cell->createTextRun('Row 1 column 2');

// Add row
echo date('H:i:s') . ' Add row'.EOL;
$row = $tableShape->createRow();
$oCell = $row->nextCell();
$oCell->createTextRun('R2C1');

$oCell = $row->nextCell();
$oCell->createTextRun('R2C2');

$oCell = $row->nextCell();
$oCell->createTextRun('R2C3');

// Save file
echo write($objPHPPresentation, basename(__FILE__, '.php'), $writers);
if (!CLI) {
    include_once 'Sample_Footer.php';
}
```

Here's what the result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Hi, dont see what is wrong! Whats your problem

Comment: Hi, take a look at the attached image in the first row the second highlighted column is missing this text "Row 1 cololum 2".

Comment: Did you try `$row->getCell(2)` to get you into cell3 of the first row, instead of just `->nextRow()`

Comment: I have not tried that yet, let me try that and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: That was it, thank you RiggsFolly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it has placed both the texts in the first column with the colspan2 set

So try this to place the cursor into the third column/cell

```
$Cell = $row->getCell(2);
$Cell->createTextRun('Row 1 column 2');
```